# Postgres: Issues with IN clause in Sql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, in-clause

I am trying to do some validations between my 2 tables(msg_dmnsn  and msg_smry_fact). Here msg_pk is the PK in msg_dmnsn. It's the foreign key in msg_smry_fact

**First Query**:

```
select count(*) from msg_dmnsn A
where A.msg_pk IN ( select distinct B.msg_pk from msg_smry_fact B
where B.sbmtd_dt < 20170316)
```

Output: 1993

**Second Query**

If I count the inner Query

```
select count(distinct B.msg_pk) from msg_smry_fact B
where B.sbmtd_dt < 20170316
```

Output: 2019

**Third Query**
This is to check if there is any

```
 select distinct B.msg_pk from msg_smry_fact B

 except

  select distinct A.msg_pk from msg_dmnsn A
```

Output: Nothing (As both of them has same data)

```
select distinct A.msg_pk from msg_dmnsn A
except
select distinct B.msg_pk from msg_smry_fact B
```

Output: Nothing (As both of them has same data)

Not sure why my first query is not returning 2019 rows? it looks like it's missing (2019-1993 =26 records) records.

From the thirds query it proves that both the table contain same data(as key matches on except)

Comment: In the first and second queries you are using `where B.sbmtd_dt < 20170316` condition, while in the third and fourth there is no any condition.

Comment: If every records matches between 2 tables(as per third Query), then a subset(with where clause) shouldn't be a problem right?

Comment: Yes you are right, sorry. Then please run: `SELECT *
FROM (select distinct B.msg_pk from msg_smry_fact B
where B.sbmtd_dt < 20170316) B
LEFT JOIN  msg_dmnsn A
ON A.msg_pk = B.msg_pk WHERE A.msg_pk IS NULL` this query should show missing 26 records (missing values of MSG_PK)..

Comment: I got it. There are some duplicates in msg_smry_fact  that is causing the issue. Thank you

Comment: `where B.sbmtd_dt < 20170316` it looks like a date. Why is it not a date?